# Match last occurrence using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a input string

```py
str = 'if [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Saturday\' or [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Sunday\' then \'Weekend\' else \'weekday\'end+[date]'
```

I want my regular expression to match the string

```py
if [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Saturday\' or [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Sunday\' then \'Weekend\' else \'weekday\'end
```

This is what I have tried:

```
(if.*?end)
```

but it doesn't match the required string and matches till

```py
if [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Saturday\' or [DATENAME_weekday]=\'Sunday\' then \'Weekend
```

Comment: Why do you use a stingy operator if you want it to be greedy?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it does. `.*?` is lazy and stops as soon as it can. There's an **end** in Week**end**.

So, either use the greedy form:

```
(if.*end)
```

or a word boundary

```
(if.*?\bend\b)
```

See [**a demo for the latter on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rJB3vt/1).